# Mac OSX forwarding hostname traffic to SSH tunnel

Tags: macos, ssh, apache-kafka, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to setup an ssh tunnel for apache kafka from my development machine to three kafka brokers listening on port 9092.  We have to talk to the kafka cluster through a jump box.  Tunneling directly to those brokers is pretty easy.  The tricky part in this is that the kafka brokers respond with an advertised hostname that must resolve locally.  In ubuntu, I can do this in two steps:

my ssh config file sets up the tunnels and maps the hostnames to the correct hosts:

```
#Forward to all the kafka brokers
LocalForward 9195 kafka01:9092
LocalForward 9196 kafka02:9092
LocalForward 9197 kafka03:9092

#remap the kafka names.  these need to resolve correctly for it to work
LocalForward kafka01.maindev.local:9092 kafka01:9092
LocalForward kafka02.maindev.local:9092 kafka02:9092
LocalForward kafka03.maindev.local:9092 kafka03:9092
```

This setup allows me to configure kafka to connect to brokers at localhost:9191, localhost:9292, localhost:9393

Then, I can just map my loopback adapter to the hostnames in /etc/hosts so they resolve properly.

```
127.0.2.1 kafka01.maindev.local
127.0.2.2 kafka02.maindev.local
127.0.2.3 kafka03.maindev.local
```

This setup works fine in Ubuntu, but I can't get it to work in a MacOSX environment.  On my mac, as soon as I bring up an alias for lo0 using

```
ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.2.1
```

Once the alias is up, nothing can be bound to the 9092 port for any of the hostnames as it's "already in use".

What am I doing wrong in setting up this tunnel on my mac?

Answer (score 1):

just went thru this for AWS MSK
get your kafka cluster boostrap servers and zookeeper ip/hostnames

```
aws kafka describe-cluster --cluster-arn <kafka arn>
```

add to your ssh config

```
LocalForward 127.0.0.1:9092  <aws-bootstrap-1>:9092
LocalForward 127.0.0.2:9092 <aws-bootstrap-2>:9092
LocalForward 127.0.0.3:9092 <aws-bootstrap-3>:9092
LocalForward 127.0.0.4:2181  <zookeeper-ip-1>:2181
LocalForward 127.0.0.5:2181  <zookeeper-ip-2>:2181
LocalForward 127.0.0.6:2181  <zookeeper-ip-2>:2181
```

edit your hosts file

```
#kafka
127.0.0.1 <aws-bootstrap-1>
127.0.0.2 <aws-bootstrap-2>
127.0.0.3 <aws-bootstrap-3>
```

for macos , create virtual interfaces

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2 up
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.3 up
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.4 up
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.5 up
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.6 up
```

ssh to ur jumphost and make sure MSK security group allows inbound for 9092 and 2181 to that host

```
./kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092,127.0.0.2:9092,127.0.0.3:9092

./kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper 127.0.0.4:2181,127.0.0.5:2181,127.0.0.6:2181 --describe --entity-name <your_topic>  --entity-type topics
```